# Swift Manipulate joint locations of Apples 3d motion cap model

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, augmented-reality, arkit

I would like to place Apple's 3d motion capture model [robot usdz](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) (found in this code sample) in a view and manually change the position of each joint. In the code sample, a BodyTrackedEntity is used to change the pose of the model based on the pose of a person in the arview, however,  I would like to change the pose of the model by supplying my own transforms. More specifically, I would like to access each joint of the model and assign it its own transform to change the model's pose.

Any suggestions on accessing and changing the location of each of the models joints manually?